# jQuery - Find form field by name

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find a specific form field (checkbox) by its name, and uncheck it. Problem is it's not working. Have tried multiple variations based on searching this site but with no success

The jQuery

```
$(".locCheck").find("[name='loc-all']").attr("checked", false);
```

And the HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class=locCheck name=loc-all checked>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change:

`$(".locCheck").find("[name='loc-all']").attr("checked", false);`

to

`$(".locCheck[name='loc-all']").prop("checked", false);`

That should work.

For checked it's `prop` that's used rather than `attr`. Also, with the selector both `.locCheck` and `[name='loc-all']` are referring to the same element. In your example you were trying to find it as a child element.